# How can i interact with my database without a modles.py | Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a discord bot that has a Flask web interface for administration. I have a running database in docker using MariaDB. Now I'm trying to write to the database from the flask app (which is running completely separate from the discord bot app which has the `models.py`), and I cannot find a way to read/write without copy/pasing the models.py into the flask-app aswell. Do I need to use something else then a `models.py`, or should it be moved to another location? Here is a small representation of the 2 apps:

`bot.py`(discord bot):

```
DATABASE_URL = f"mysql+pymysql://root:{str(os.environ.get('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'))}@host/{str(os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'))}"
engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL
)
conn = engine.connect()
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
db = SessionLocal()
Base = declarative_base()

bot = commands.Bot()

# All bot commands
@...

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

`models.py` (Same Folder as bot.py):

```
from bot import Base, engine
class ...(Base):
    ...

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

`app.py` (Flask app):

```
# Either this, or the same way of connecting as in bot.py:
load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env'))

DATABASE_URL = f"mysql+pymysql://root:{str(os.environ.get('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'))}@192.168.2.46/{str(os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'))}"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATABASE_URL
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# All app paths
@...
```

Now I'd like to write to the database from the app.py, how would I do this?